# Get property value in spring view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cas

I am trying to get a property set in a spring context file in my view.

I am customizing CAS 4.0  with a maven overlay, so I do not have access to the controller. I have set values in a model and sent that off to the view thousands of times, but how do I skip the controller and go straight from context to view?

I want something like this in my context:

```
<bean id="forwardURL" value="/asdlfjk">
```

and in my view:

```
<a href="${forwardURL}">click me</a>
```

Thank You

Comment: You can get that value using java code in write that much code in scriptlet tag. and access that variable in your anchor tag.

Comment: Could you expand on that?  Like with a code example?